# "You can add more at the end of this list BUT before making a new entry make sure its not already present"

Tags: vocabulary

This is a tip that is being included with an Excel form, which requires the end user to fill some technical information. In the given scenario, the end user would not be very tech-literate, so we want to keep things clear, compact and easy to communicate and so we added tips like:

> ***“Gena provides this default set of information. You can add more at the end of this list BUT before making a new entry make sure its
>   not already present.”***

But we the team feel some things missing in it. We want to make this tip more ‘usable’ and easy to understand for the user.

**I seek your precious suggestion over how this tip can be made more clear, compact and easy to communicate.***

*PS: ‘Gena’ is the name of our product, to sound it like more direct and personalized so we  used it as a communicating entity here.*

Comment: You could make the question more *clear, compact and easy to communicate*, and more importantly, grammatically correct, so we may try to answer it well.

Comment: With respect, your product does not appear very user-friendly. Why should the user carry the burden of checking for duplicates when this is precisely the kind of thing computer systems are best at? I suspect if the product was improved, the job of instructing the user would become much easier or even unnecessary.

Comment: @Kris: yes, as English isn't my primary language thats why i decided to come here, to ask help from people who know more about it than me. my apologies for the grammatical mistakes in it.

Comment: @Ed Guiness: The excel form isnt our product, its just questionnaire to ask user requirements to configure our product acc to their needs and to keep it easy and accessible to everyone without any special requirements we used excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Read the following information provided by Gena. Please feel free to add to this list anything you wish to be included."

That may serve the purpose adequately.